# Find centers of light spot on a picture?

Tags: matlab

I have a picture like this:

[image]

and I want to find the cordinates of the centers of the light spots.

I am a beginner and I thought to do this thing:

```
for i = 1:size2
    for j=1:size2
        if(E(i,j)>1)
            f(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end
```

where size2 is the dimension of the matrix and E(i,j) is the matrix whose imagesc(E(:,:)) gives the first picture
and then applying imfindcircles, but I dont have good results.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you could post the image file you used? It'll be easier to work with rather than the plot.

Comment: Do you know how can I share it? @MichaelTr7

Comment: Possibly by uploading it to Google Drive or GitHub and linking it here?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z6YKwVK4aExYCwDGq6UIc0RTpkLCC8UT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Any chance you could change the drive permissions so I can download it?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Try now:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K4hcZFo9wjFCZvDlVyP4eUzaieCs7N5v/view?usp=sharing